# CSS is not applied to Flutter webview

Tags: css, flutter, webview

The CSS applies to Flutter webview 4.0.7 if it is embedded in HTML with `<style type="text/css"> </style>`. However it doesn't work with `<link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/api/css/reregistration.css">`

Javascript unrestricted is set in WebView controller.

The same code works fine in Chrome desktop, i.e, CSS is served.

Someone could help?

I tried to put CSS not embedded but doesn't render as CSS specifies.